# Is it possible to execute more requests than there are threads in thread pool?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, testing, integration-testing

I develop web application with Java and Spring. In order to check how system behaves when more than one request is coming i created test:

```
@Test
public void shouldHandleMultipleRequests() throws Exception {
    //given
    final String endpoint = "http://localhost:9000/upload";
    final File file = new File(format("src/test/resources/files/%s", 
        "file.txt"));  
    //when
    final CompletableFuture<String> response1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 
        Try.ofFailable(() -> 
        HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(
        createHttpPost(endpoint, file))).orElse(null).getEntity().toString());
    final CompletableFuture<String> response2 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 
        Try.ofFailable(() -> 
        HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(
        createHttpPost(endpoint,file))).orElse(null).getEntity().toString());  
    assertThat(response1.get().contains("Something")); 
    assertThat(response2.get().contains("Something"));
```

}

Everything works just fine, however i noticed, that if i try to run more than 3 requests there is delay between first 3 requests and every next one.

My questions are

- Am I right that this behavior is related to number of threads on my processor(4 threaded processor,3 threads for requests and awaiting for response, and one for app)?
- If there is any way to send more than 3 requests simultaneously (and later retrieve response, of course)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`CompletableFuture.supplyAsync`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-) uses common `ForkJoinPool` to submit tasks which thread count by default is limited by number of hardware threads returned by `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`. You however can create your own pool and use it for your tasks using two-argument [`supplyAsync`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.concurrent.Executor-):

```
ForkJoinPool myPool = new ForkJoinPool(100); // number of tasks executed in parallel

CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(..., myPool);
```

For network requests it's quite normal to have more threads than CPU cores.

Answer (score 1):

Java threads are so called soft threads which are not related with processor cores/threads number.

Usually, HTTP Servers and thus Servlets/App containers works with thread pools, that means that once you reach the thread pool upper limit, the rest of the requests remains blocked. That is the blocking approach.

However, there is another option to configure connectors that are non-blocking. You can get more deep knowledge reading this [Tomcat Connectors Document](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html). So, as you can see, you can adjust server behavior because it is a matter of connectors configuration.

Of course, you can spawn more than three threads at the same time and receive `Future` results.